# Simulating a simple Call Stack in java

Tags: java, stack, callstack

I'm trying to simulate a simple call stack in java, and just run it with simple math functions (such as Fibonacci, Factorial) that I've implemented previously.

Logic wise here's what I'm attempting to do:

Whenever a method is called, Push a 'stack frame' onto a regular stack.

• Stack frame would contain local variables, parameters

• Store the method names and arguments on to the stack as a String.

• As the method is exited, these values are popped off of the stack.

• Should be able to display the 'Call Stack' at any time by calling a `display()` method. (Already implemented in my stack class)

I'm having a little trouble understanding the logic around it, this is all I've got at the moment:

```
public class CallStack 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int num1 = 5; 
        int num2 = 10; 
        MyStack B = new MyStack(3); 

        Fibonacci.CalcFib(num1); 
        B.push("Fibonacci.CalcFib(num1)");
        B.push(String.valueOf(num1));
        B.display();  
        B.pop();  

        System.out.println();
        Factorial.CalcFact(num2);
        B.push("Factorial.CalcFib(num2)");
        B.push(String.valueOf(num2));
        B.display();
        B.pop(); 
    }
}
```

I know this isn't how it should be implemented, but I can't seem to understand how else I would go about doing this. And how I would pop that method off the stack once it's done.

Any help/tips would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I don't see how you can do this in Java, unless you are writing some kind of p-code interpreter. You don't have access to return addresses, for a start. I also don't see the point of pushing the method name.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is already inside the Java programming language and its runtime implementation. You cannot intermingle with it, and that is good.

So make up your mind: create your own programming language and interpreter in whichever language you pick and you have full control on the stack and variables, or accept Java is doing it for you and your best visibility is to use a debugger.

Almost all universities have model computers with an appropriate model language for such a learning exercise, so it is not totally off the world.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware it's a runtime implementation, the only purpose was to merely simulate the Call Stack by pushing methods onto a stack when they're called, and popping them off when they're done. And to be able to call a ```Stack.display()``` method to view the stack in the program, that's all.

Comment: @Robin_Hood You still don't have access to return addresses. You need to specify your task in greater detail, in your question.

Comment: Sure thing! I've tried to make the task a little clearer. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should investigate is Reverse Polish Notation (RPN) which is a way of expressing arithmetic operations and function calls that can easily be translated to a stack.

In RPN the infix expression:

2 + 3 * 5

is written as:

```
2 3 5 * +
```

It is processed by pushing the operands onto a stack. When an operator is encountered the number of parameters required are popped and evaluated and the result pushed back on the stack.

So, in this example, 2 3 and 5 are pushed. When * is encountered 3 and 5 are popped and multiplied and the result (15) pushed. When + is encountered 2 and 15 are popped and added and the result is pushed. The result is left on the stack.

Method calls work the same as operators. (In fact, operators can be thought off as "special" methods). For example:

```
substr("hello", 2, 4)
```

would be written as:

```
"hello" 
2 
4
new MethodName("substr")
```

With the last item, I am wrapping the method name in an object of type `MethodName` (a class I invented) to distinguish it from `String` types.

You will store these items in a Java `Stack<Object>` type and use the `push` and `pop` operations there.

After you have popped your arguments and method name off the stack you will have to write a lot of code to interpret what you have and call the appropriate function, either using reflection or hard-coding the method calls.

I not prepared to go into more detail as this is quite a lot of work. If this is an exercise, then you will have to work some of it out yourself. If it is not, then there are libraries to do this kind of thing. For example, JEP.

Comment: Thank You! I actually just implemented an infix->postfix and rpn in Java, so this is actually really helpful! Makes sense, I think I should be able to do this. Thanks again :)

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please upvote and accept the answer if you think it best answered your question.

Comment: @rghome I fail to see how RPN helped you with a problem about method calls, return addresses, etc.

Comment: @user207421 if you implement an expression evaluator for RPN (as I have) you will find it also works for function calls as well as operators. Learning RPN is just an easy and well documented way to approach the solution.

Comment: @rghome Of course, but it doesn't do anything about stack frames or return addresses. But of course those have now been removed from the question.